# Triggering validation on a second form based on the first form submit

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have two forms on a page. I would like to trigger validation of form A when form B is submitted. Is this possible?

Comment: out of curiosity, why?

Comment: Has to do with some page layout requirements beyond my control. There are several fields that are mirrored to hidden fields on form b so I am trying to get validation messages to appear on the visible fields on form a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need capture the submit of form B and then call validation on form A. Something like:

```
$('#formB').submit(function(e){
     //some logic for formB

     $('#formA').validate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible, in form B make your button as simple button with type="button" not submit
then do this:

```
$("form B button").click(function(){
 //validate form A
 $("form B").submit();
})
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#formB').submit(function(e){

     return $('#formA').valid();
});
```

This will submit formB if formA is valid, cause if you don't return false it's going to submit formB anyway.